# Jquery buttons to replace image several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The title is perhaps poorly worded so ill explain what i mean here.

I have three buttons that i want to replace the image of a div based on what they press. So for example, the first image would be a forest. One button would correspond the choice of going further in so that button replaces that image with another one. One button would make you pick something up/go to another place, with the latter option replacing the current image with another and the last one would make you itch your head.

Making a button replace an image once isnt that big deal but i dont see how youre supposed to do it if you want the buttons to replace the images with new images once you pressed a button?

Comment: try using an image carousel... there are a lot of examples on the web... here is one -> http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

Answer (score 0):

just change css background-image : url like I did bellow. It basically changes background-image of central part (to url of grass.jpg for example) of page when you click on button with id (id #grass). 
I made the image name and Id the same just to make it more understandable.
Hope it helps.

```
$('#grass').click(function(){
  $('.central').css('background-image', 'url("img/grass.jpg")');
});
$('#flower').click(function(){
  $('.central').css('background-image', 'url("img/flower.jpg")');
});
$('#forest').click(function(){
  $('.central').css('background-image', 'url("img/forest.jpg")');
});
```

Comment: Yeah thats a good idea actually. But lets say we're on the first image. The first button takes us to grass.jpg, the second button takes us to flower.jpg and the third one takes us to forest.jpg. Lets say i press forest.jpg, how do i make the buttons have new options? Wont they still have grass.jpg, flower.jpg and forest.jpg as options?

Comment: I keep reading your question but I don't get what you actually need. Can you post some code or something to help us with understanding it better?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fully understand your question. Assuming you want to iterate over a list of images:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="imageDisplay"></div>

        <button id="previous" type="button" onclick="displayPrevious()" >previous</button>
        <button id="next" type="button" onclick="displayNext()" >next</button>

        <script>

            var imagesList = ['banana.png',
                              'apple.png',
                              'orange.png'];

            var currentIndex = 0;

            function displayPrevious() {
                if(currentIndex > 0) {
                    currentIndex--;
                    setBackGroundImage(imagesList[currentIndex]);
                }
            }


            function displayNext() {
                if(currentIndex < imagesList.length) {
                    currentIndex++;
                    setBackGroundImage(imagesList[currentIndex]);
                }
            }


            function setBackGroundImage(imageName) {
                var imageDisplayDiv = document.getElementById('imageDisplay');
                imageDisplayDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/"+imageName+"')";
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad wording. So basically, i have a div with an image in it and three buttons beneath that div. 

Each of the buttons will load another image. So for example when you load up the site, the first button will load one picture, the second button will load another picture and the third button will load a third picture. 

The thing im not sure how to do is how the buttons will have new choices once i press one of the buttons. If i press button 1, button 1 will still replace the image with image 1, button 2 with image 2 and button 3 with image 3.